# How to grant privileges to a user based on database name (PSQL)

Tags: sql, database, psql, privileges

I want to know if there's a way of giving privileges to a user on specific databases based on their name and programmatically.

For example, let's say we have the databases db1, db2, x_db1, x_db2 and I want to grant all privileges to a user on only x_db1 and x_db2. I don't want to execute

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE x_db1 TO user_x;
```

and

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE x_db2 TO user_x;
```

I want to know if there's something like GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE x_* TO user_x; so I don't have to grant privileges to the user every time a new db gets added.

Answer (score 0):

I believe GRANT does not take wildcards, but, as in [similar-topic](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/104172/postgresql-grant-all-on-mutliple-tables-using-like), you can use procedures to achieve it:
DO

```
$$
BEGIN
EXECUTE (
   SELECT 'GRANT ALL ON TABLE '
       || string_agg (format('%I.%I', table_schema, table_name), ',')
       || ' TO test'
   FROM   information_schema.tables
   WHERE  table_schema = 'public'
   AND    table_name LIKE 'test\_%'
   );
END
$$;
```